What is the name for the "strap wrapper thing" that is often used on the straps of bags to distribute weight more evenly on the shoulder?
This kind of device is commonly used with camera bag straps.
See the image (copied below) at this Amazon link as an example.


Need to be more specific than that. There are so many kinds. What kind of bag. Is the strap placed on the shoulder?

@fev I added a link and an image.

Maybe pads, padding?

Padding seems to describe the function, but I feel like there has to be a more specific word for this thing.

They’re called shoulder pads. You can search on Amazon for “shoulder pads backpack” to see some add-ons for sale.

Specifically, "shoulder strap pads" is what I found most often.

In your image there are two items: a shoulder strap and a shoulder pad.

Thanks! I guess that's no obvious way to differentiate these from other shoulder pads without additional context, such as these? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoulder_pad_(fashion)

@Xanne I suggest posting that as an answer.

@fev But the title text makes it clear which part they're asking about.
